# Can someone explain this Kotlin expression?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I am learning android development using Kotlin. Being primarily a web developer, I am new to both technology.

While looking for API-29 Connectivity Solution (`NetworkInfo` and `getActiveNetworkInfo` are deprecated in `API-29`), I ran across this expression for variable declaration.

```
 protected var callbackFunction: ((Boolean) -> Unit) = {}

 abstract fun startListening(callback: (Boolean) -> Unit)
```

How would I interpret this? Do I say, *variable callbackFunction is of type Boolean, Or of type Unit*. Or something else. In that abstract function, is callback type of Boolean or Unit or something else?

Also I am a bit confused, about the curly braces. Does it mean variable is initialized by an empty anonymous function (something like in JavaScript) or is it something entirely different concept?

Comment: It's an empty [lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax), which meets the requirement of taking one argument and returning nothing. The type of callbackFunction is a function that you call back with a Boolean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin supports functional  programming, which means that functions are treated as first class citizens in Kotlin. They can be passed around or returned from functions, just like any other variable.

So,

```
 protected var callbackFunction: ((Boolean) -> Unit) = {}
```

`callbackFunction` is a variable that implements a Function `interface`. You can effectively say that this is a lambda. To define the lambda **type**, after `:`, it takes a `Boolean` as a parameter and after arrow `->` means that it returns `Unit` which is `void` in terms of Java. After the `=`, we give it a body with the curly braces.

Here is how it would look like when invoked:

```
 class Test {
    var callbackFunction: ((Boolean) -> Unit) = {}
    fun higherOrderFunction(block: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
         block(true)
     }
   }

   fun main() {
      Test().higherOrderFunction { it ->
          println(it) //print true
      }  
   }
```

If we look at the bytecode, we can see what it's doing under the hood:

### Decompiled Test class

```
  public final class Test {
  @NotNull
   private Function1 callbackFunction;  

  @NotNull
  public final Function1 getCallbackFunction() {
    return this.callbackFunction;
  }

   public final void setCallbackFunction(@NotNull Function1 var1) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(var1, "<set-?>");
    this.callbackFunction = var1;
  }

   public Test() {
     this.callbackFunction = (Function1)null.INSTANCE;
   }
 }
```

Check how the `callbackFunction` is of `Function1` type. Now, let see the declaration of `Function1`.

```
/** A function that takes 1 argument. */
public interface Function1<in P1, out R> : Function<R> {
  /** Invokes the function with the specified argument. */
  public operator fun invoke(p1: P1): R
}
```

You can pass `callbackFunction` variable to `startListening()` abstract method because this method accepts a lambda that takes a Boolean as a paramter and returns Unit. So, `callbackFunction` matches the parameter of the abstract method and we can now pass it.

> How would I interpret this?

- You can say that, "callbackFunction is a lambda that takes Boolean as an argument and returns nothing."

> In that abstract function, is callback type of Boolean or Unit or something else?

- It takes a lambda that(again), requires a Boolean as an argument and returns nothing.

> about the curly braces. Does it mean variable is initialized by an empty anonymous function?

- Just like we can give curly braces to an `abstract` declaration to give it concrete implementation, we can do the same here.

Comment: You are awesome.. Thanks. I knew it was lambdas but couldn't properly interpret the expression. Got confused as I didn't knew functions could be assigned to variables similar to javascript. I hate lambdas for its crypticness.