# Kotlin Higher-order functions

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, kotlin-higher-order-functions

I am new in functional programming language and I just came through a new concept called Higher-order function.

I have seen Higher-order functions such as `filter()`, `map()`, `flatMap()`, `take()`, `drop()` and `zip()`. I have only seen these higher order functions in kotlin documentation.

`My question is:` These are the only these higher-order functions available in kotlin or there are more higher-order functions also available.

I am not sure, Can we also create higher-order functions for personal use or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every function which takes a lambda as a parameter to one or more of its arguments or return a lambda is a higher-order function.

Comment: Means, we can create our own higher-order functions as well??

Comment: Can you give some brief details about it in the answer? Your comment is helpful, it would be great that you can add some more context, So, I and others in the community understand it more properly. Also, I can accept your answer.

Comment: Take a look at my answers, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58250195/9968399) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920850/using-lambdas-does-not-compile-when-trying-to-pass-in-a-method-expecting-a-sam-i/57921406#57921406). Hopefully, it should somewhat help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Comparison to Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/comparison-to-java.html) page's 4th point, Kotlin has proper function types, as opposed to Java's SAM-conversions.

What I mean by that is if you want to accept a function or some sort of code **in Java** that you can call inside a function you **need an external interface having exactly 1 method which is aware of the return type and the parameter signature**.

For example in Java:

```java
// You can't create this unless you create FuncInterface defining its parameter and return type
MyFuncInterface a = (s) -> System.out.println(s);

interface MyFuncInterface {
    public void myMethod(String s);
}

// now call a like
a.myMethod("Hello World"); // will print: Hello World
a.myMethod("Test");        // will print: Test
```

While it is not the case in kotlin, you can create lambda without creating an interface here.

For example same code in Kotlin could be converted into:

```kotlin
val a: (String) -> Unit = { println(it) }
// or like this: val a: (String) -> Unit = { s -> println(s) }

// call like this
a("Hello World") // will print: Hello World
a("Test")        // will print: Test
```

---

Since Kotlin has proper function types, you can make a function accept a function type or return one, which is then be called a [Higher-Order Function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types).

Concept is similar:

```kotlin
// This is a higher order functon, takes a callable function `f`
fun operatesFOn(num1: Int, num2: Int, f: (Int, Int) -> Int) {
    // this types are useful as callbacks, instead of taking nums and passing them
    // you can compute heavy tasks and when they complete call f with the result
    return f(num1, num2)
}

// lambda can be put outside the parentheses if it is last parameter
// also is another higher order function which calls the lambda passed with the object it was called on as a parameter
operatesFOn(3, 4) { a, b -> a + b }.also { println(it) } // prints: 7
operatesFOn(5, 7) { a, b -> a * b }.also { println(it) } // prints: 35
```

There are some other cool modifiers as well for higher order functions like the [inline](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) modifier.

```kotlin
inline fun operatesFOn(num1: Int, num2: Int, f: (Int, Int) -> Int) {
    return f(num1, num2)
}
```

The above one will work similar but the **lambda will instead be inlined at the call-site** in compile time, to decrease the call-stack increasing the performance. as mentioned in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) as well:

> Using higher-order functions imposes certain runtime penalties: each function is an object, and it captures a closure, i.e. those variables that are accessed in the body of the function. Memory allocations (both for function objects and classes) and virtual calls introduce runtime overhead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Animesh. It is really in-depth. I like the examples which clear my doubt somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are many more higher-order functions in Kotlin, e.g., `apply`, `also`, `lazy`, `let`, `onSuccess`, `recover`, `recoverCatching`, `repeat`, `run`, `runCatching`, `suspend`, `with`, `use`.  Explore the reference documentation for functions that consume other functions as values, e.g., https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/functional-programming.html#nice-utility-functions.

Yes, users can define higher-order functions.  Refer to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html for info about how to define and use higher-order functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Venkatesh. For, giving me answers to my question and sharing those links.